# Something re-creates ConfigMap in custom k8s namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, prometheus-operator

Have a Prometheus operator on GKE and some ConfigMap with Prometheus rules, created by me. Today I figured out, that I can't change/delete that ConfigMap anymore. Each time it gets recreated in the previous state. Back in days, it wasn't immutable.

What can be the cause of that?

- K8S master: 1.13.7-gke.24
- K8S node: 1.13.6-gke.13
- Prometheus: v2.4.3
- Prometheus-operator: v0.24.0
- Configmap-reload: v0.0.1
- Prometheus-config-reloader: v0.24.0

Comment: Is there any error message? if there are, include them to the question.

Comment: Nope, just `configured` or `deleted`. No errors at all.

Comment: For those who forgot that there's `PrometheusRule` CRD, like I did: edit those `PrometheusRule` custom resources, not the ConfigMaps. Solved.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. If you have an actually useful answer, post it as an answer in the big friendly box below, and accept it. If not, perhaps you should simply delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus Operator acts on [CRDs](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator#customresourcedefinitions). These objects are continually watched, and any drift configuration will trigger a config-reload.

The operator is intended to fully control the ConfigMap; if you directly edit it, the config-reloader will eventually revert your changes to match the CRD configs.

The correct way to edit your rules is by changing the [`PrometheusRule`](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/29199d546e0bcb98b82f90b266eb437f1b1934c2/Documentation/design.md#prometheusrule) object. Your changes will be caught by the operator, which will update the ConfigMap and trigger a config-reload.